# My google extension is not showing a phrase from my JavaScript list

Tags: javascript, html, manifest, manifest.json

I have already written code for the manifest, html, and javascript for my code. In basic, the extension is meant to show a fortune from my array written in my javascript. Basically you click the extension and it randomly chooses a phrase. For some reason my code is unable to pick a phrase and I don't know why, any help?

**after implementing the code below that you have generously provided, I am getting an error code in the chrome extension as follows:

Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://ogs.google.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
at i.requestFrameworkInitializer (chrome-extension://hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd/onloadwff.js:71:780730)
at Object.initialize (chrome-extension://hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd/onloadwff.js:71:778514)
at Object.sendRequest (chrome-extension://hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd/onloadwff.js:71:778654)
at Object.requestFunction (chrome-extension://hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd/onloadwff.js:71:804161)
at Object.getLinkedAccount (chrome-extension://hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd/onloadwff.js:71:748593)
at HTMLDocument. (chrome-extension://hdokiejnpimakedhajhdlcegeplioahd/onloadwff.js:71:803471)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      /* Add some basic styling to the extension's UI */
      body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
      }
      h1 {
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      p {
        font-size: 14px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src = "js/popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Fortune of the Day</h1>
    <p id="fortune"></p> 
  </body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
console.log("Displaying fortune list...");

// Define an array of fortunes
const fortunes = [
  "You will have a great day today.",
  "Expect good news soon.",
  "You will meet a new friend today.",
  "Your hard work will pay off soon.",
  "A small change will bring big results."
];

// Generate a random fortune
function getFortune() {
  return fortunes[Math.floor(Math.random() * fortunes.length)];
}

// Save the current fortune to the extension's storage
function saveFortune(fortune) {
  chrome.storage.local.set({ fortune: fortune });
}

// Retrieve the current fortune from the extension's storage
function getSavedFortune(callback) {
  chrome.storage.local.get("fortune", callback);
}

// Display the current fortune in the extension's UI
function displayFortune(fortune) {
  const fortuneElement = document.getElementById("fortune");
  fortuneElement.innerText = fortune;
}

// Initialize the extension by retrieving the current fortune from the extension's storage
getSavedFortune(function(items) {
  let fortune = items.fortune;
  if (!fortune) {
    // If no fortune is saved, generate a new one and save it
    fortune = getFortune();
    saveFortune(fortune);
  }
  displayFortune(fortune);
});

// Listen for the extension to be activated and refresh the fortune
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
  const fortune = getFortune();
  saveFortune(fortune);
  displayFortune(fortune);
});
```

MANIFEST:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Fortune of the Day",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Displays a different fortune every day",
    "permissions": [
      "storage",
      "activeTab"
    ],
    "background": {
      "script": ["js/popup.js"]
    },
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "html/popup.html"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: `storage.local.set` and `storage.local.get` are promise based.

Comment: Adding on to what @damonholden said, this means that you must await those functions. Once you do, it should be able to load properly.

Comment: do you have a github repo for this so we can debug the extension?

Comment: Here is the link to the github repo: https://github.com/matthieud1/extension.git

Comment: Will clone and debug on my end to see if I can find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `storage.local.set` and `storage.local.get` are promise based methods ([see usage example on chrome extension API docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#usage)). You will need to handle this in your JavaScript code. This solution should work:

```
// Define an array of fortunes
const fortunes = [
  'You will have a great day today.',
  'Expect good news soon.',
  'You will meet a new friend today.',
  'Your hard work will pay off soon.',
  'A small change will bring big results.',
];

// Generate a random fortune
function getFortune() {
  return fortunes[Math.floor(Math.random() * fortunes.length)];
}

// Save the current fortune to the extension's storage
function saveFortune(fortune, callback) {
  chrome.storage.local.set({ fortune: fortune }).then(() => callback(fortune));
}

// Retrieve the current fortune from the extension's storage
function getSavedFortune(callback) {
  chrome.storage.local.get(['fortune']).then(callback);
}

// Display the current fortune in the extension's UI
function displayFortune(fortune) {
  const fortuneElement = document.getElementById('fortune');
  fortuneElement.innerText = fortune;
}

// Initialize the extension by retrieving the current fortune from the extension's storage
getSavedFortune((items) => {
  let fortune = items.fortune;
  if (!fortune) {
    // If no fortune is saved, generate a new one and save it
    fortune = getFortune();
    saveFortune(fortune, displayFortune);

    return;
  }
  displayFortune(fortune);
});

// Listen for the extension to be activated and refresh the fortune
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(() => {
  const fortune = getFortune();
  saveFortune(fortune, displayFortune);
});
```

Additionally in your `popup.html` file, change the `<script>` element to the following:

```
<script defer src="../js/popup.js"></script>
```

your previous script tag was pointing to a test directory which doesn't exist. Also, because your `<script>` element is in the `<head>` element of the HTML file and performs DOM manipulation when interpreted, you must defer the execution of the script with the `defer` attribute.

Hope this helps.

Comment: for some reason when I click my extension icon, it only shows my h1: Fortune of the Day, and then nothing under, I implemented your code and nothing seems to change. Is it more so a misunderstanding on my part?

Comment: modified the answer to address the issue.